# SSH2 Alive connection/persistence connection

Tags: php, phpseclib, ssh2, ssh2-sftp, spryker

I'm using **phpseclib** with version 3 library of php.
When i connect to SFTP after execution of one method it has been disconnected automatically. I have checked **SSH2.php** where distruct method is written and disconnect method is also called inside it.Like this

`public function __destruct() { $this->disconnect(); }`

I want a connection which will persist util i disconnect.

if I remove this __destruct again connection is closed automatically. Please suggest if anyone hava a solution for this. We are using this in spryker.

There is one more method **setKeepAlive**. i used this method as well, but not luck.

Comment: Sounds like `$ssh->setTimeout(0);` will do what you're wanting?

Comment: I want alive connection during my process so, I can execute multiple requests to the SFTP server after that it will disconnect.

Comment: I fixed it.  I used a singleton pattern for the object of SFTP.php and flysystem. It works.